# Override c++ streams

Tags: c++, overriding

In a C++ program, we have 3 streams: `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. Can I override these in a console application and use them in a application that uses forms?

For example, if in some base class, I have `cout<< "..."`, can I "redirect" to something visual (like a Windows Form)?

Comment: Ok, I mean something visual, not the console

Comment: Note, that usually overriding streams behaviour is done by implementing std::streambuf interface. That's rather complex task, so you should probably use other answers provided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is having a class which wraps around an iostream like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#define LOG Log()

class Log
{
   public:
      Log(){}
      ~Log()
      {
         // Add an newline.
         std::cout << std::endl;
      }


      template<typename T>
      Log &operator << (const T &t)
      {
         std::cout << t;
         return * this;
      }
};
```

Then, whenever you want to change where the data goes, you just change the class behavior.
Here is how you use the class:

```
 LOG << "Use this like an iostream.";
```

[edit]
As potato swatter suggested, I'll add an example with something other than cout:

```
#include <sstream>
#define LOG Log()

// An example with a string stream.
class Log
{
   private:
      static std::stringstream buf;
   public:
      Log(){}
      ~Log()
      {
         // Add an newline.
         buf << std::endl;
      }


      template<typename T>
      Log &operator << (const T &t)
      {
         buf << t;
         return * this;
      }
};

// Define the static member, somewhere in an implementation file.
std::stringstream Log::buf;
```

As for why you should try this instead of inheriting from something like a string stream, mainly because you can easily change where the Logger outputs to dynamically. For instance, you could have three different output streams, and use a static member variable to swap between at runtime:

```
class Log
{
   private:
      static int outputIndex = 0;
      // Add a few static streams in here.
      static std::stringstream bufOne;
      static std::stringstream bufTwo;
      static std::stringstream bufThree;
   public:
      // Constructor/ destructor goes here.

      template<typename T>
      Log &operator << (const T &t)
      {
         // Switch between different outputs.
         switch (outputIndex)
         {
            case 1:
               bufOne << t;
               break;
            case 2:
               bufTwo << t;
            case 3:
               bufThree << t;
            default:
               std::cout << t;
               break;
         }
         return * this;
      }

      static void setOutputIndex(int _outputIndex)
      {
          outputIndex = _outputIndex;
      }
};

// In use
LOG << "Print to stream 1";
Log::setOutputIndex(2);
LOG << "Print to stream 2";
Log::setOutputIndex(3);
LOG << "Print to stream 3";
Log::setOutputIndex(0);
LOG << "Print to cout";
```

This can easily be expanded to create a powerful way of dealing with logging. You could add filestreams, use std::cerr, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make a new ostream derived class and use that?

Comment: This is basically starting from scratch. What if, for example, the existing code uses format manipulators or `endl`? Also, this example doesn't illustrate how to interface with something besides `cout`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code I use to redirect `std::cout` to a GUI on Windows:

```
struct STDOUT_BLOCK : SLIST_ENTRY
{
    char sz[];
};

class capturebuf : public std::stringbuf
{
protected:
    virtual int sync()
    {
        if (g_threadUI && g_hwndProgressDialog) {
            // ensure NUL termination
            overflow(0);
            // allocate space
            STDOUT_BLOCK* pBlock = (STDOUT_BLOCK*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof *pBlock + pptr() - pbase(), MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT);
            // copy buffer into string
            strcpy(pBlock->sz, pbase());
            // clear buffer
            str(std::string());
            // queue string
            ::InterlockedPushEntrySList(g_slistStdout, pBlock);
            // kick to log window
            ::PostMessageA(g_hwndProgressDialog, WM_APP, 0, 0);
        }
        return __super::sync();
    }
};
```

Then inside `main()`:

```
capturebuf altout;
std::cout.set_rdbuf(&altout);
```

Of course, you then need to handle the `WM_APP` message in your window procedure and pull the strings off the SList.  But this handles the `cout` redirection part.

As jweyrich correctly notes, you need to change the `streambuf*` back before `altout` goes out of scope.  This code will do so:

```
struct scoped_cout_streambuf_association
{
    std::streambuf* orig;
    scoped_cout_streambuf_association( std::streambuf& buf )
        : orig(std::cout.rdbuf())
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(&buf);
    }

    ~scoped_cout_streambuf_association()
    {
        std::cout.rdbuf(orig);
    }
};
```

And inside `main`:

```
capturebuf altout;
scoped_cout_streambuf_association redirect(altout);
```

Comment: Don't forget to restore the original rdbuf before exiting, otherwise it might crash.

Comment: There is no function `set_rdbuf`, just two overloads of `ios::rdbuf`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: There is in Visual C++, and this code is windows-specific, although the general idea is quite portable the details aren't.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to put an `iostream` interface on something else is to use the `stringstream`/`istringstream`/`ostringstream` classes in `<sstream>`.

The best way is to change the use of `cin`, `cout`, etc to parameters of type `istream &` and `ostream &`. If that is really impossible, you can modify `cin.rdbuf()` to point at the stream you wish to modify, but that is extremely hackish and won't work with multithreading.

Copy text from the form into an `istringstream`, then pass it to the existing code as an `istream &`. When you're done, read the results from the `stringstream` passed as `ostream &` that replaced `cout` and copy it into the form.

Do not declare arguments of type `istringstream &` or `ostringstream &`. Use the base classes.

If you really want, you could subclass `std::basic_stringbuf< char >` and override the `sync` and `underflow` virtual functions to tie streams directly to text fields. But that's fairly advanced and likely not worth it.

Comment: You don't modify `cin.rdbuf()`, you call it.  And it's not "hackish", it's exactly how the standard library iostreams are designed to be used.

Comment: @Ben: I'm referring to modifying the underlying buffer pointer of the global variable `cin` to point at a local variable, so that a called function can access the local through a global. That is very hackish.

Comment: Again, the standard iostreams are designed to have their `streambuf` objects replaced, and they provide public APIs to do so cleanly.  That's how polymorphism is implemented in the standard library iostreams.

Comment: @Ben: Merely calling `rdbuf` isn't the issue here, using a library global variable as a function argument is. I think this is fairly clear…