# Capture/redirect cout to a function

Tags: c++, capture, cout

Is it possible to capture cout in a way so that every standard output (`cout << "example";`) automatically calls a function (`myfunc("example");`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override c++ streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169136/override-c-streams)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a class which had the appropriate `operator<<` overloads and create a global instance called `cout` and to `using std::whatever` instead of `using namespace std;`. It would then be easy enough to switch back and forth from your custom `cout` to `std::cout`.

That's just one solution though (which may require a decent amount of work, more than you want to spend), I'm sure other people know better ways.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that's probably the best approach and there is [a working code sample in "Override c++ streams"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169136/override-c-streams#7169195) (thanks @Tomalak Geret'kal for the link). I'll keep using namespace std though and call my stringstream something else.

Comment: @basic6 ok, so you'd have something like `MyStream sout;` and everything would be `sout << stuff;`. And then when you wanted to change back to `cout` you chould change `MyStream sout;` to `ostream& sout = cout;` and then it'd be like `cout` again. Will you mark this as the answer if it's answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a new class inherited from `std::streambuf` and overload the virtual function `virtual int overflow(int c);`.  You then need to use `rdbuf()` on `cout` to this class.

After you connect it up to `cout` the `overflow()` will be called with every character output.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class MyCOutClass: public std::streambuf
{
private:
    virtual int overflow(int c)
    {
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            return !EOF;
        }
        else
        {
            if(c=='\n')
                printf("\r");
            printf("%c",c);

            return c;
        }
    }
};

class MyCOutClass MyCOut;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout.rdbuf(&MyCOut);

    std::cout << "testing" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```